# Why autowired Environment bean is null if I register AmazonS3 bean with name "amazonS3"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

I have a simple SpringBoot 2.3.5 application with `spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging` starter added. I have some configuration class as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
   @Autowired
   private Environment env;

   @Bean
   public AmazonS3 amazonS3() {
        AmazonS3ClientBuilder builder = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard();
        builder.enablePathStyleAccess();
        AmazonS3 amazonS3 = builder.build();
        return amazonS3;
   }

}
```

Now when I run the application the `@Autowired` environment is `null`. If I rename the bean registration method from `amazonS3` to anything say `amazonS3Bean` then `environment` bean is properly initialised and is not `null`.

Why `amazonS3` name is so special and why it is making `environment` bean as NULL?

Comment: Likely because the autoconfiguration has a bean with the same name? There should be an error if that were the case unless you have `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` set

Comment: Yes, I do have spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true. But how AmazonS3 bean name is making Environment as null? Not only Environment, but any Configuration Property beans (@ConfigurationProperties) also becoming NULL.

Comment: Seems like `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding` value doesn't affect this behaviour. Tried with both `true` and `false` and getting the same issue.